# How can I prevent cache override expiry time in redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I have a generic method called `save` with  Redis template  :

```
redisTemplate.expire(cacheType.name(), redisPropertyConfiguration.getTimeToLive(), TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

every time I called this method expire of the Redis template override the expiration time, I wanna prevent the expiration time and put it if the expiration time end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected because [`expire(K key, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#expire-K-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) (wrapper of the [EXPIRE](https://redis.io/commands/expire) Redis command) is documented as

> Set time to live for given key.

You ask :

> ```
>  I wanna prevent the expiration time and put it if the expiration time end
> ```

You cannot prevent expiration if you check the key after the expiration time.

What you can do is adding again the key in the case if that has expired.
In Redis, the command [`TTL fooKey`](https://redis.io/commands/ttl) returns the remaining time to live of the key.
And good news : the Spring Boot Redis Template API also implements that :

[`public Long getExpire(K key)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#getExpire-K-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

> Get the time to live for key in seconds.

So you could write something like that :

```
if (redisTemplate.getExpire(cacheType.name()) == -1L){
  // re-add the key-value
  redisTemplate.opsForValue.set(cacheType.name(), fooValue);
}
```

Comment: redisTemplate.getExpire(cacheType.name()) always returned  ( -1 )

Comment: If a negative is returned by `getExpire()`, it will say that either the key was set as "never expire" or the key doesn't exit (any longer). You cannot prevent expiration if you check the key after the expiration time. So to fix your issue you should add a second check to recreate the cached key when it has expired.